# Why can I conclude $Q_n \xrightarrow{\mathscr{D}} Q$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, weak-convergence, polish-spaces

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are Polish spaces. Suppose $Z \subset X$ is a borelian subset of $X$. Let $\varphi : Z \to Y$ continuos and $(R_n)_{n \geq 1}$ probabilities on $X$ such that for all $n \geq 1$ $R_n(Z)=1$. Let us define $Q_n$ the image probability of $R_n$ through $\varphi$ and suppose $R_n \xrightarrow{\mathscr{D}} R$ (i.e. $R_n$ converges in distribution to $R$). If $Q$ is the image probability of $R$ through $\varphi$ can I conclude $Q_n \xrightarrow{\mathscr{D}} Q$?

If yes, why?

I have just observed that if $Z$ is closed then is a Polish space and thus we can use reduce to study the case $\varphi : X \to Y$.
It is enough to prove $R(A) \leq \liminf R_n(A)$ for any open set $A$.

I do not know hot to approach the case $\varphi: Z \subset X \to Y$.

Comment: Perhaps consider that any Borel measure on a Polish space is inner regular, which means it can be approximated from within to an arbitrary degree by a closed set.

Comment: @LostStatistician18 That's interesting. Do you know how to write it formally? Because the close set one may choose depend from the probability.

Comment: If $Z$ is Borel in $X$, then there is a finer polish topology on $X$ that has the same Borel sets as the original topology, but in which $Z$ is clopen, so you can always assume that $Z$ is Polish

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Thank you for the suggestion. Do you have any reference or could you please expain me why?

Comment: @FilippoGiovagnini Sure, see theorem 13.1 in Kechris *Classical Descriptive Set Theory* (13.2 and 13.3 are needed for the proof as well)

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti  Thank you so much.